# Devise Admin Role: PG::Error: ERROR: relation "admins" already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise

After successfully configuring devise with users I am now trying to add an Admin role in preparation of using rails_admin.

I followed these instructions (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role) to add the admin role to devise even though the migration generated looked completely different from that in the instructions. I then ran "bundle exec rake db:migrate" only to get the error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "admins" already exists
```

At this point I had not attempted to install rails_admin because I wanted to get devise working fully first.

Any ideas why I got this error when I did not previously have an admin model?

Comment: Maybe your table (or the entire database) already exists? As a normal plain-mortal pg-user I would first try to *comment it out* But, for rails-people, this kind of stuff might be a bit more complex.

Comment: powerful. worked! thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PG::Error: ERROR: relation "refinery\_blog\_posts" already exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602218/pgerror-error-relation-refinery-blog-posts-already-exists)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution thanks to wildplasser: run db:drop -> db:create -> db:migrate to reset the database!

Comment: can you drop only the users table?  Not using a migration?