# Why rake db:migrate doesn't work when adding Admin to User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, rails-migrations

I don't know why I can't add the column "Admin" to my Users table. I run in the terminal "rails g migration AddAdminToUsers admin:boolean" and it creates the file in db/migrate. When I run rake db:migrate I get the following error:

*"PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "admin" of relation "users" already exists"*

In the schema.rb file I don't see that there is a column for admin. When I run rake db:migrate:status I can see the status for "Add admin to users" is "down" while everything else is "up". I can resolve the issue by typing rails db:migrate:reset but then I lose the data of my Users along with other data.

**How can I add the admin column to my Users table?**

Comment: Please post your migration as well as the relevant portions of your schema.rb file. Also, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389841/devise-admin-role-pgerror-error-relation-admins-already-exists

Comment: You can check in rails condole by typing: `User.first` to see the the first user object has ad admin column. Looks like you schema and migration are out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR: column "admin" of relation "users" already exists"
```

The error message is very clear. You already have an `admin` column in your `users` table. You have to remove that before you can add `admin` column to your `users` table.

To remove the already existing `admin` column, generate a migration:

```
rails g migration RemoveAdminFromUsers admin:boolean
```

then run the migration to remove the `admin` from `users`:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Now you can add it back again:

```
rails g migration AddAdminToUsers admin:boolean
```

Comment: Thank you @KMRakibulIslam for your answer. I never added the column Admin before, do you know if Admin is a column that comes automatically like the column ID? I didn't specifically added the column ID, but it was added automatically when I created the model User.

Comment: No, that does not come by default. Did you add any gems luke `active_admin` or `devise`?

Comment: Yes, I did add the gem Devise.

Comment: I suspect you added admin by mistake before. Because the error message is very clear. Try my answer to just remove it first, then try to add it. It should work. Let me know if not!

Comment: Thanks! Your code works. I was curious to know why I was getting the error. In the past I must have added Admin, but it was not in my schema.rb file. This was strange to me. I appreciate your help and advice.

Comment: You are most welcome :) I am glad that I could help :-)